# How do I configure Xcode to use Maven

Tags: xcode, maven, geotools

XCode comes out of the box with support for Ant (with several sample projects you can generate).

How can I configure XCode to use maven pom.xml files?

Fore reference the project I am trying to set up is here:

- http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/guide/building/maven/build.html

It makes use of nested folders, each with their own pom.xml, all controlled with the usual maven build targets of:

- mvn clean install
- mvn install -o
- mvn install -o -DskipTests

What makes this a challenge is the nested modules; each of which installs into the local ~/.m2/repository.

For comparison: The eclipse build system references jars in the ~/.m2/repository for external dependencies, while still allowing modules in the project to refer to each other.

I would like a way to set up something similar for XCode.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [Xcode Maven Plugin](http://sap-production.github.io/xcode-maven-plugin/site/index.html) to use maven in your Xcode.

[this](https://github.com/sap-production/xcode-maven-plugin) is the git hub repository.

The following prerequisites have to be fulfilled in order to use the Xcode Maven plugin:

- Mac OS X >= 10.7(Lion)+  The build has to run on a Mac computer.
- JRE 6+ The Java runtime environment has to be installed on the computer.
- Maven >= 3.0.2 Maven 3 has to be installed and configured correctly so that is has access to central repositories.
- Xcode >= 4.4 Xcode 4.4 or higher has to be installed as the plugin performs
- Xcode command line calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can use do this:

```
mvn ant:ant
```

to create a full ant build and then use that from xcode. You'll need to re-run that task every time you change the pom. You can add a shell task to do run that as the first step in your build.

You could also try to turn the `$M2_HOME/bin/mvn` into a shell task in the build. That might work but you'll never be able to debug issues with it without lots of black magic.

I would try the prior before the later.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that there are no answers to this question posted.  If it is not possible, then maybe you can just have maven call an ant target to build the xcode?